# best practice to get the default object wrapper?

Tags: freemarker

when creating custom method, I implements TemplateMethodModelEx and returns SimpleSequence object.
according to the API, I should use this constructor:

```
SimpleSequence(ObjectWrapper wrapper)
```

since I am setting incompatibleImprovements as 2.3.24, the doc said I can simply use Configuration instance's getObjectWrapper(). My problem is when implementing TemplateMethodModelEx, I have no access to the current config unless I pass cfg to the method's constuctor. then the root.put would look like:

```
root.put("getMeList", new GetMeListMethod(cfg));
```

this looks odd to me, i wonder whats the right to construct this kind of SimpleSquence model and whats the right way to get the default object wrapper.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass in the `ObjectWrapper` as the constructor parameter. (It's unrelated to `incompatibleImprovements` 2.3.24.) Any `TemplateModel` that creates other `TemplateModel`-s (like `TemplteSequenceModel`-s, `TemplateHashModel`-s, `TemplateMethodModel`-s) used to work like that. This is normally not apparent because they are created *by* an `ObjectWrapper`. If you do the `TemplateModel`-s manually however (which is fine), then you will face this fact.